# Store command with multi line output to variable or file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, output, store

I am trying to store a command prompt command to a variable in Powershell, as well as outputting it to a file. Since the command has 3 lines of output, nothing gets stored as a variable or written to file. The only thing that happens when I attempt to store or output to file, is that the output gets printed to the screen.

input:

```
java -version
```

output:

```
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b25)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.251-b25, mixed mode)
```

I have tried the following which did not work:

```
$variable = (java -version)
$variable = cmd /c "java -version")
java -version | out-file test.txt
```

[image: output only prints to screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Looks like I misread your question, original answer at the bottom*

`java.exe` likely outputs the version info to the standard error stream, so you'll have to redirect it into the standard output stream first:

```
$version = java -version 2>&1
```

But since PowerShell will attempt to wrap the output from the error stream in `ErrorRecord`'s, we need to convert those back to strings again:

```
$version = java -version 2>&1 |ForEach-Object ToString
```

To learn more about the different output streams in PowerShell and how to redirect them, see the [`about_Redirection` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection)

---

Either store the command and arguments in string variables, then invoke with `&`:

```
$command = 'java'
$arguments = '-version'
# ... later in the script:
$javaVersion = & $command $arguments
```

Alternatively create a scriptblock with the command expression:

```
$javaVersionCommand = {
  java -version
}
# ... later in the script:
$javaVersion = & $javaVersionCommand
```

Comment: So what does 2>&1 mean exactly? This seems to be the key to making this work.

Comment: @Aaron It means "Take the data pushed to stream 2 (the error stream) and merge it into stream 1 (the output stream)", I've added a link to the relevant documentation in the answer as well